# Flatting a dataframe with all values of a column into one

Tags: r

I have a data frame in this format

```
str(df2)
'data.frame':   2 obs. of  10 variables:
 $ stc1 : Factor w/ 2 levels "price_of_A_stock",..: 1 2
 $ stc2 : Factor w/ 2 levels "price_of_B_stock",..: 1 2
 $ stc3 : Factor w/ 2 levels "price_of_C_stock",..: 1 2
```

I would like to make it to have all values from every column into one without the names of its column

In order to make it I used this:

```
r_df <- as.data.frame(t(df2))
```

But the result I have is this:

```
str(r_df)
'data.frame':   10 obs. of  2 variables:
 $ 1: Factor w/ 10 levels "price_of_A_stock",..: 3 6 8 1 5 9 10 7 4 2
  ..- attr(*, "names")= chr  "stc1" "stc2" "stc3" "stc4" ...
 $ 2: Factor w/ 10 levels "price_of_B_stock",..: 7 9 10 6 1 8 4 3 2 5
  ..- attr(*, "names")= chr  "stc1" "stc2" "stc3" "stc4" ...
```

Comment: I can't figure out how to recreate your dataframe. Can you include that in your question, possibly by using `dput`?

Comment: Can you please add an example how the result should look like exactly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can use `unlist`

```
data.frame(Col1= unlist(df2, use.names=FALSE))
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also use the melt() function from the reshape2 package e.g.

```
library(reshape2)
r_df<-as.data.frame(melt(df2)$value)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `unname` and `unlist`.

```
unname(unlist(df2))
```