# Combining multiple columns in one R

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyr

How can I combine multiple all dataframe's columns in just 1 column? , in an efficient way... I mean not using the column names to do it, using `dplyr` or `tidyr` on R, cause I have too much columns (10.000+)

For example, converting this data frame

```
  > Multiple_dataframe
      a    b    c

      1    4    7
      2    5    8
      3    6    9
```

to

```
  > Uni_dataframe
     d

     1
     2
     3
     4
     5
     6
     7
     8
     9
```

I looked around Stack Overflow but without success.

Edit: [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34368598/flatting-a-dataframe-with-all-values-of-a-column-into-one) are a answers for a similar question, the difference is there they did not use dplyr.

Comment: Are those multiple dataframes or multiple columns of single dataframe ?

Comment: @RonakShah Multiple columns of single data frame

Answer (score 6, accepted):

We can use `unlist`

```
Uni_dataframe <- data.frame(d = unlist( Multiple_dataframe, use.names = FALSE))
```

---

Or using `dplyr/tidyr` (as the question is specific about it)

```
library(tidyverse)
Uni_dataframe <- gather(Multiple_dataframe, key, d) %>%
                                             select(-key)
```